# Google App Engine Python error : "Blob() argument should be str instance, not unicode "

Tags: python, image, google-app-engine

I have been trying to save images on GAE data store but i get the following error:

***"Blob() argument should be str instance, not unicode".***

Any ideas how to get past this ?

The way i read and (trying to) write the images is :

```
...
avatar_data = self.request.get('pic_input') # pic_input is the name of the form
artist.picture = db.Blob(avatar_data) # artist is an entity type that has a picture field of type db.Blob()
...
```

I tried also to wrap avatar_data inside str() which actually got the string to be saved in the data store but my file didn't display !!!

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Have you tried [encoding](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/) yet?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams If his image is a Unicode string, something is seriously wrong, and encoding it won't make things better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What are you trying to do?

The response from `pic_input` is a unicode string, but you are trying to store it as if it were just binary bits. Are these binary bits or a string?

If they are binary bits, they should not have been encoded to unicode in the first place.

If it is a string, then you shouldn't store it in a `Blob` but a `Text` or `String`.

The reason the form upload is sending an encoded string (unicode) is because, you did not use the proper enctype in the form.

```
<form method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
```

Should solve this and your code will just work fine.

Comment: pic_input represents image file. Apparently they encode to unicode.

Comment: An image file *path*? It can't be an image file because you can't store raw bytes in unicode.  Even if it somehow encoded properly you can't rely on that working. Are you sure `pic_input` isn't base64 encoded or something like that?

Comment: Html form tag did some encoding. Following your point that they shouldnt be getting encoded in the first place, i've include the enctype attr so that it looks like <form method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >. Works now.

Answer (score 3):

Encode it!

```
avatar_data.encode('utf-8')
```

Replace utf-8 with the encoding you want, e.g., `'ascii'`.

Comment: No! He's trying to store an image. If the data is a unicode string, something is seriously wrong, and encoding it again won't fix it.